# How find and edit links in a HTML code with?

Tags: php, html

I want to find and edit links in a HTML code by this method:

1. find links
2. select original URL
3. replace in href

I can get this code by PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser, but I can't edit links.

I tested this PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser, but it doesn't work:

```
foreach($html->find('a') as $mylink){
preg_match('/q=(.+)&amp;sa=/U', $mylink, $mylink_3);
$mylink->href = $mylink_3;
}
```

My original source is:

```
<div>

<h3 class="r"><a href="/url?q=http://www.w3schools.com/php/&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=0CBQQFjAAahUKEwj78p-XtcbHAhVEjiwKHbjpC0g&amp;usg=AFQjCNGazDJ5puRFYuhWUs0-q5Yq9EnkVw"><b>PHP</b>my php</a></h3>
</div><div>
<h3 class="r"><a href="/url?q=https://www.php.net/&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=0CB8QFjABahUKEwj78p-XtcbHAhVEjiwKHbjpC0g&amp;usg=AFQjCNFekxb7S2RFF0wizEyO0Swem8s0-w"><b>PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor</b></a></h3>
</div>
```

I want to have final code like this:

```
<div>

<h3 class="r"><a href="/url?q=http://www.w3schools.com/php/"><b>PHP</b>my php</a></h3>
</div><div>
<h3 class="r"><a href="https://www.php.net/"><b>PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor</b></a></h3>
</div>
```

I've tried a lot, and every function that can be used I tested, but this does not work.

Comment: Please include the code you've tried in your question

Comment: I'm going to guestimate that you're looking for something like [htmlspecialchars](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php). DOM Parser may have some sort of `raw` function somewhere in there too, not sure though.

Comment: How are the URLs generated in the backend? Do you have access to the PHP function or is it possible to solve this through the client-side?

Comment: Questions or issues with my answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
$dom_document = new DOMDocument();      
$dom_document->loadHTML($your_html);
$dom_xpath = new DOMXpath($dom_document);

$hrefs = $dom_xpath->query('//a/child::getAttribute(\'href\')');
foreach ($hrefs as $href)
{
    $href->data = 'new_href';
}
```

or //a/@href

Comment: thank you for help . i tested that code but occur this error : Warning: DOMXPath::query() [domxpath.query]: Invalid expression

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to shorten links after an ampersand. This should accomplish that:

```
    $input = '<div>
<h3 class="r"><a href="/url?q=http://www.w3schools.com/php/&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=0CBQQFjAAahUKEwj78p-XtcbHAhVEjiwKHbjpC0g&amp;usg=AFQjCNGazDJ5puRFYuhWUs0-q5Yq9EnkVw"><b>PHP</b>my php</a></h3>
</div><div>
<h3 class="r"><a href="/url?q=https://www.php.net/&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=0CB8QFjABahUKEwj78p-XtcbHAhVEjiwKHbjpC0g&amp;usg=AFQjCNFekxb7S2RFF0wizEyO0Swem8s0-w"><b>PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor</b></a></h3>
</div>';
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($input);
    $links = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');
    foreach ($links as $link) {
        $link->setAttribute('href', preg_replace('~&.*~', '', $link->getAttribute('href')));
    }
    echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><div>

<h3 class="r"><a href="/url?q=http://www.w3schools.com/php/"><b>PHP</b>my php</a></h3>
</div><div>
<h3 class="r"><a href="/url?q=https://www.php.net/"><b>PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor</b></a></h3>
</div></body></html>
```

The regex says find an `&` and then everything else. Then replace that with nothing. The `~` are delimiters saying where the regex starts and ends. The `.` is any character and the `*` is zero or more occurrences.